# Executando Angullar 2 em http-server

Tags: angular

Tenho uma apliação em Angular2 e foi gerado /dist onde contem o codigo HTML, CSS e Javascript executei o codigo utilizando o http-server e no tomcat. Meu problema é que quando rodo as minhas rotas fica assim -> http://localhost:4201/dashboard mas o problema é quando dou refresh na pagina não encontra pois teria que adicionar '#/' exemplo: http://localhost:4201/#/dashboard

Comment: Você desabilitou as rotas no modo html5?

Comment: Como faço pra desabilitar?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver adicionando dentro da pasta /dist o .htaccess

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

Para usar rotas sem o modo HTML5, usando hashbang, você precisa fazer essa configuração no seu módulo de rotas principais:

```
...
imports: [
  ...
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ...
]
...
```

Conforme a doc: [Appendix: LocationStrategy and browser URL styles](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles)

Comment: Esta utilizando dessa maneira, mas quando gerava o build parava de funcionar.